# Exporting Nao robot Simulator in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, robot

I'm using the Coregraphe 2.1.4 software as simulator, I'd like to export this simulator into Unity 3D in order to make a videogame where people can interact and play with Nao.

I've successfully exported the model of the Robot in Unity but i can not animate it.

Is it possible to export the Nao robot simulator in Unity3D? Or, are there other way to run the simulator in Unity3D?

Thank :)

Comment: To be honest it sounds like you've stolen the "Nao" 3D model from their software! That's just a commercial product isn't it? It's not in the slightest available for open source, or anything like that - unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've successfully exported the model of the Robot in Unity but i can
>   not animate it.

Export it to a 3D software such as Maya or Blender, then animate it there and import the 3D model and the animation back to Unity. Blender is free. You just need to learn animation.

> Is it possible to export the Nao robot simulator in Unity3D?

No. You can't export a software to Unity. If the company that made it produced a DLL plugin for Unity then you can. They don't have plugin for Unity, so you can't.

> are there other way to run the simulator in Unity3D?

No. All the answer to your questions are No, No and No. Although, you can animate your 3D model in a 3D software then import into Unity.

Comment: i wouldnt say that its impossible, but it certainly is no plug and play solution and an answer is completely out of scope for such format.

Comment: @yes Right now it is impossible. The simulator was made to work by itself. If you find any possible way to do it, please drop it as the answer and I will upvote it right away.

Comment: i think with a lot of effort it should work? http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/ref/simulator_sdk.html this program he mentions probably also only uses those dlls? but i only just googled that becaue i wanted to know what the question is about :D

Comment: i might have been to hastly in my judgement, but im still reading.

Comment: @yes. The link you posted shows you can make you can make a plugin to control the robot. The plugin can instantiate a robot but all those things will be running in the Nao whatever window. It won't be displayed on Unity. This is his question: Is it possible to export the Nao robot simulator in Unity3D? Or, are there other way to run the simulator in Unity3D? He did not say he wants to control the robot from Unity. He said **export** to unity and **the simulator in Unity3D**. Look at those keywords carefully.

Comment: It looks like he wants to display the thing in Unity and you can't. He even tried exporting the 3D model which exported but the animation did not work. He's not trying to control it from Unity to that software. He wants everything to run and display in unity somehow which according to me again, is not possible. Of-couse, you may be able to do this by reverse  engineering but that's pointless as he wont be able to release his app.

Comment: on this site it states the simulation can be run independent from choreograph http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/robot/nao/doc/dev/tools/robot-simulation.html i thought he wants some sort of view for the data the simulation produces? ofc you have to find a way to map all that to the actual 3d model in unity, thats what i mean with a lot of effort. but you should get all the actuator and joints and whatnot. isnt that the same as bones and muscles?

Comment: Yeah. It still runs in  Robot view which is part of the Nao software. Robot view is an app that displays the robot in 3D world. It does not provide an API to read the screen from Robot view and display them in Unity or third party software. It wont display in Unity. Assuming the question was "How to control Nao from Unity". Then yes, but that's not even the question.

Comment: First of all. thanks to both of you for the answers. I don't need to control Nao from Unity, the robot will follow the simulator's instructions. My question is if is it possible to run this simulator(or other simulators like V-rep) in Unity, or if I can write a script or a remote api which makes the simulator able to run in Unity. Sorry for my bad English, I hope you'll understand what I'm trying to explain :(

Comment: hi @yes.  I suggest you are really misunderstanding how unity, models, and software works.

Comment: @Bobafett **I don't need to control Nao from Unity, the robot will follow the simulator's instructions. My question is if is it possible to run this simulator(or other simulators like V-rep) in Unity**. I don't know any other simuliation software but I will give you a deep honest answer. You can't run that in Unity. You simply can't. I am glad you verified you want to run it in Unity and not control it from Unity. You can't.

Comment: @Bobafett The good news is that you can develop your own simulation API. Yes, you **can** in Unity but you must be very good at math because of too many physics calculations required. You also need to learn 3D modeling. So that you can design a simple 3D object, import to Unity and start writing your own API. Unity can do it. NASA does it. Many top agency and companies in the USA uses Unity for simulation and this includes car manufactures. You can but you can't use Nao. You gotta do it from scratch.

Comment: hey @Bobafett don't forget to tick this answer, as a new user it's important to tick an answer to keep the board tidy.  cheers